# Segfaults when trying to free pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, free

I have a code like this

```
void find_groupings ()

  int *bandwidths;
  int *execution_time;

  bandwidths = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*node_count); // node_count is glbl
  execution_time = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*node_count);
  //other mallocs, other code etc

  while (condition) {
    // lot of code
    find_bandwidths(bandwidths);
    find_execution_time(execution_time);
    //lot of code
  }

  free(bandwidths);
  free(execution_time);

}
```

code segfaults at line  "free(execution_time);"

```
Thread 1 "vx_tutorial_exe" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xf7dd0cd9 in _int_free (av=0xf7f15780 <main_arena>, p=<optimized out>, have_lock=0) at malloc.c:4005
4005    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

I can guarantee that "execution_time" doesn't go out of bound inside the find_execution_time()
I believe I free every malloc I do in the code

Also found that pointer value for execution_time is the same just before it crashes at the free() using gdb

tried valgrind but, it doesn't help since the program segfaults

What could be the problem here ?

Comment: valgrind should help you. Clearly you have trashed your heap in the `other code` bits. Or maybe your mallocs fail. At least test for null

Comment: Agreed that the heap has been corrupted somehow, and free() is crashing because it is encountering the corrupted heap metadata.  If valgrind isn't helping, the other thing you can do is start temporarily #ifdef'ing out various parts of the code and re-running the program to see if the crash goes away.  Eventually you can narrow it down to where the suspect subset of the code is small enough that the bug will become apparent.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please tell me how to use valgrind for this.
this is the response I get
vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xC5 0xF8 0x10 0x83
==7406== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x80cf291.
==7406==    at 0x80CF291: tivxBamCreateHandleSingleNode 

==7406== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
==7406== did not recognise.

Comment: Thank you Jeremy, your advice worked! Thank you pm100!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the whole issue was, in a malloc I had casted it with a wrong type

for buffers I had malloced it as

```
buffers  = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*node_count);
```

It should have been

```
buffers  = (buffer *)malloc(sizeof(buffer)*node_count);
```

buffer is a structure type in my code.

It's so weird that it crashed in a way that is impossible to find out based on error messages.

Thank you Jeremy! and pm100